# I'm a resident of Monaco and my future wife is a US citizen and resident. Will I have tax obligations once married?

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident

As my header explains, I'm concerned with the possible tax ramifications once married let alone being in a de facto relationship. For example, France is harsh when it comes to taxes.  If she lived there and if I never visit the country, I'm obligated to pay full taxes there on my worldwide income. I'm hoping this isn't the case for the USA which I plan to never surpass the 6 month mark per year.  Any advice appreciated

Comment: Do be mindful of state law. New York considers residency as 90 continuous days.

Answer (score 6):

No, so long as you remain a non-resident, you will not need to file a US tax return.  Your wife will need to continue to file either as Married Filing Separately or, possibly, as Head of Household:
https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/us-citizens-and-resident-aliens-abroad-head-of-household